# VBA 実行時エラー'91'の解決法

Tags: vba, excel

#### 前提・実現したいこと

VBAでエクセルの勤務表から勤務日等を抽出し、別のソフトウェアに読み込ませる転換マクロツールを作っています。
エクセルの勤務表のシートから、VBAツールのシートに勤務日を抽出転換する機能を実装中に以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
実行時エラー'91'
オブジェクト変数またはWithブロック変数が設定されていません。
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```vb
'ファイルの選択ダイアログを表示して
'ファイルのパスを取得します
Private Sub btnGetFilePath()

Dim fType, prompt As String
Dim fPath As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'選択できるファイルの種類はすべてのファイル
fType = ""

'ダイアログのタイトルを指定
prompt = "Excelファイルを選択して下さい"
'ファイル参照ダイアログの表示
fPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(fType, , prompt)

If fPath = False Then
'ダイアログでキャンセルボタンが押された場合は処理を終了します
End
End If

'B2セルにファイル名をセット
ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = fPath

'読み込んだファイルを元して、このファイルのシート2に出力する
'シート2をシート1と合わせて、TOTが読めるようyyyymmdd合わせる
'数値で持ってきて、表のシート1の年月と合わせて,20200301と表示
'シート2を保存してcsvにする
Dim Target As Workbook
Set Target = Workbooks.Open(fPath)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Target.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A2")
Target.Sheets(1).Range("H2").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A3")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:Work\Book1.xlsm"'抽出転換されたシートを保存

End Sub
```

#### 試したこと

デバッグのポインタが36行目のTarget.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A2")で止まります。
調べたもののSetステートメントはついており、原因がわかりませんでした。
もしおわかりになればお願いします。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Excel 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一応解決しました。別の方の環境でもこのVBAを実行して貰ったのですが正常に動いたため、私のPCの調子がおかしいとの仮説を立てPCを再起動しエクセルVBAを実行した所、このVBAマクロツールが動作しました。環境に依存しているらしいので根本的な原因も調査中です。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Target.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A2")
> ```

は`Target.`が不足していて

```
Target.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy Target.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
```

の誤りだったりしませんか？

Comment: sayuriさん　ご協力ありがとうございます。Target.は不足していないと思います。このTarget.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A2")
では左のTarget.Sheet(1)が新規にダイアログから読み込む勤務表.xlsm、右のSheets(2).Rangeがその勤務表.xlsmの値を抽出転換したシートで別のエクセルファイルとなっております。一応解決したので解決方法を別に書きます。